# R: Create a more readable X-axis after binning data in ggplot2. Turn bins into whole numbers

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dummy variable call it "drink" and a corresponding age variable that represents a precise age estimate (several decimal points) for each person in a dataset.  I want to first "bin" the age variable, extracting the mean value for each bin based on the "drink" dummy, and then graph the result.  My code to do so looks like this:

```
df$bins <- cut(df$age, seq(from = 17, to = 31, by = .2), include.lowest = TRUE)
df.plot <- ddply(df, .(bins), summarise, avg.drink = mean(drinks_alcohol))
qplot(bins, avg.drink, data = df.plot)
```

This works well enough, but the x-axis in the graph is unreadable because it corresponds to the length size of the bins.  Is there a way to make the modify the X-axis to show, for example, ages 19-23 only, with the "ticks" still aligning with the correct bins?  For example, in my current code there is a bin for (19, 19.2] and another bin for (20, 20.2].  I would want only the bins that start in whole numbers to be identified on the X-axis with the first number (19, 20), not the second (19.2, 20.2) shown.

Is there any straightforward way to do this?

Comment: You can specify whatever labels you want with the `labels` argument of `scale_x_discrete`. See the help help for examples. An empty string `""` is a blank label.

Comment: And if you only want to plot some of your data, then subset your data before (or inside) the plot.

Comment: I was familiar (or thought I was) with the `scale_x_discrete` function, but there are hundreds of bins.  Do I need to manually specify blank strings for all the ones I don't want to show up?

Comment: You can also set labels in the `cut` function, for example, to label with the start of the intervals, `cut(..., labels = head(seq(from = 17, to = 31, by = 0.2), -1))`

Comment: You could write a custom formatter using some regex. They're pretty simple, see, e.g., [comma_format() and comma()](https://github.com/hadley/scales/blob/master/R/formatter.r).

Comment: And I wouldn't recommend manually specifying blank strings, I'd recommend doing it programmatically. If you're going by `0.2`, then every fifth one is what you want to keep. `bin_starts = seq(17, 30.8, by = 0.2)`, then `bin_labels = ifelse(bin_starts - trunc(bin_starts) < 0.00001, as.character("x"), "")`.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant stuff.  I didn't even know half of these things existed.  If you want to throw all that into an answer, I'd be happy to give you a check.

Comment: Presumably I manually replace the X's with the real number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most direct way to specify axis labels is with the appropriate `scale` function... in the case of factors on the x axis, `scale_x_discrete`. It will use whatever labels you give it with the `labels` argument, or you can give it a function that formats things as you like.

To "manually" specify the labels, you just need to create a vector of appropriate length. In this case, if you factor values go are intervals beginning with `seq(17, 31.8, by = 0.2)` and you want to label bins beginning with integers, then your labels vector will be

```
bin_starts = seq(17, 31.8, by = 0.2)
bin_labels = ifelse(bin_starts - trunc(bin_starts) < 0.0001, as.character(bin_starts), "")
```

(I use the `a - b < 0.0001` in case of precision problems, though it shouldn't be a problem in this particular case).

A more robust solution would to label the factor levels with the number at the start of the interval from the beginning. `cut` also has a `labels` argument.

```
my_breaks = seq(17, 32, by = 0.2)
df$bins <- cut(df$age, breaks = my_breaks, labels = head(my_breaks, -1),
               include.lowest = TRUE)
```

You could then fairly easily write a formatter (following [templates from the `scales` package](https://github.com/hadley/scales/blob/master/R/formatter.r)) to print only the ones you want:

```
int_only = function(x) {
    # test if we can coerce to numeric, if not do nothing
    if (any(is.na(as.numeric(x)))) return(x)
    # otherwise convert to numeric and return integers and blanks as labels
    x = as.numeric(x)
    return(ifelse(x - trunc(x) < 1e-10, as.character(x), ""))
}
```

Then, using the nicely formatted data created above, you should be able to pass `int_only` as a formatter function to `labels` to get the labels you want. (Note: untested! necessary tweaks left as an exercise for the reader, though I'll gladly accept edits :) )

Comment: Spectacular work!  Not sure if I'm competent enough to make direct edits.  But I believe `head(breaks, -1)` should be `head(my_breaks, -1)`  And for readers like myself who don't know how to use a formatter function it looks like this: `scale_x_discrete(labels= int_only(my_breaks))`  Asante sana.

Comment: Hamna shida. If the formatter is designed to work on the scale values (I just modified the function to do that) then you should only need to give the function to `labels`, that is, `scale_x_discrete(labels = int_only)`.

Comment: Niliishi Zanzibar kwa miezi minne -- niliona kwamba unaweza kuzungumza Kiswahili :-)

Comment: Niliishi [Mlangali](https://goo.gl/maps/f6LJD6u2Ais) miezi miwili. Nimefurahi kukukatana :)